# Count how many times a user logged in 1x, 2x, 3x

Tags: sql

I'm just beginning to learn SQL and this has completely stumped me. I join two tables on user_id where the event was a login. So far so good. Then I need to group those occurrences and count them to return the answer. How many times did users log in 1x, 2x, 3x...?

What I am having trouble with is referencing the first count (occurrences) and the fact that I can't group by occurrences since it is an aggregate function.

Here is the code, it returns two columns, user_id and occurrences. The data is on [www.mode.com](http://www.mode.com).

```sql
SELECT
  Users.user_id,
  COUNT(Users.user_id) AS occurrences
FROM
  tutorial.playbook_users Users
  JOIN tutorial.playbook_events EVENTS ON Users.user_id = EVENTS.user_id
WHERE
  EVENTS.event_name = 'login'
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2
```

Comment: You need to group by user id

Comment: You're grouping by user_id as luk2302 pointed out. Your query is fine, just GROUP BY Users.user_id ORDER BY 2 
 and it should work.

Comment: I am already grouping by Users.user_id.
GROUP BY 1 in this case is the same as GROUP BY Users.user_id.

The code runs as posted above but I need it to group the occurrences and count them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just aggregate it again

```
SELECT 
  q.UserLogins AS occurrences, 
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    Users.user_id,
    COUNT(EVENTS.user_id) AS UserLogins
  FROM tutorial.playbook_users Users 
  JOIN tutorial.playbook_events EVENTS 
    ON EVENTS.user_id = Users.user_id
   AND EVENTS.event_name = 'login'
  GROUP BY Users.user_id
) q
GROUP BY q.UserLogins
ORDER BY q.UserLogins
```

Comment: Reading and understanding that snippet was really helpful and answers my question. I learned something. Thank you!

Comment: @Bogi That's good. Btw, if you also want the 0 logins. Then make it a `LEFT JOIN`